# Dojo datagrid parent as innerHTML element id

Tags: datagrid, dojo, innerhtml

Notice that nothing gets rendered if the "if (true)" is not toggled to false. In other words, why is there no rendering if the parent node passed to the data grid constructor is a innerHTML element id. If that is the case, can someone let me know how to do this?

```
    
        
            @import "dojo/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css";
            @import "dojo/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css";
            @import "dojo/resources/dojo.css"
        
        
        
    
    
        dojo.require("dijit._Widget");
        dojo.require("dijit._Templated");
        dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
        dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");

        dojo.addOnLoad(function()
        {
            dojo.require('dojo.parser');
        });

        dojo.ready(function()
        {
            dojo.parser.parse();

            var top = "root";
            if (true) // ';
                dojo.parser.parse();
                top = "first";
            }

            // Create the data grid parameters.
            var layout =
            [
                { name: 'Name', field: 'name', width: '100px' },
                { name: 'Color', field: 'color', width: '100px' }
            ];

            var dataStore =
            {
                data :
                {
                    items :
                    [
                        { name : 'John Doe', color: 'green' },
                        { name : 'Jane Doe', color: 'red' }
                    ]
                }
            };

            var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid
            (
                {
                    store: new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore(dataStore),
                    clientSort: true,
                    structure: layout
                },
                dojo.byId(top)
            );

            grid.startup();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="top"></div>
```

javascript:

```
dojo.require("dijit._Widget");
dojo.require("dijit._Templated");
dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
dojo.require('dojo.parser');
dojo.ready(function()
{
    // Create the data grid parameters.
    var layout =
    [
        { name: 'Name', field: 'name', width: '100px' },
        { name: 'Color', field: 'color', width: '100px' }
    ];
    var dataStore = {
        data :
        {items :[
        { name : 'John Doe', color: 'green' },
        { name : 'Jane Doe', color: 'red' }
        ],
        label:'name',
        identifier:'color'
        }
    };

    var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid
    (
        {
        store: new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore(dataStore),
        clientSort: true,
        structure: layout
        },
        "top" // this id should be there in HTML .
    );
});
```